# Requests.get how to open the same session

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using requests.get() on the url https://www.websudoku.com/. But the values of sudoku I will be scrapping via bs4 and requests would be different when I reopen the webpage using the same url.This would make it impossible for me to check on the values.

How do I ensure that the session I am using for my requests is same as the one I open on a browser.

Comment: usuall servers use `cookies` to keep information about session. But it can be problem when you will run browser and code at the same time because it may get different  changes in cookies and it can be problem to synchronize it. Maybe use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser and you wil see browser all time.

Comment: You can use requests.Session(), this allows you to keep the http request data so you can hit the same site with the same information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have the same cookies as seen in your browser, but you could store the cookies received in your script for next time.

Use a `requests.Session()` to make all of your requests. This will keep any cookies whilst the script runs. At the end you could then save them to a file for use the next time.

Try the following kind of approach:

```py
import os
import pickle
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

cookie_file = 'websudoku.pkl'

with requests.Session() as session:
    # Any existing cookies?
    if os.path.exists(cookie_file):
        with open(cookie_file, 'rb') as f_cookies:
            session.cookies.update(pickle.load(f_cookies))

    req = session.get("https://www.websudoku.com/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
    print(soup)

    # Save current cookies
    with open(cookie_file, 'wb') as f_cookies:
        pickle.dump(session.cookies, f_cookies)
```